# Inserting values into multiple MySQL tables at once

Tags: php, mysql

I've created mini content management system. Now got afew questions

I'm filtering posts with following function

```
function filter($data, $db)
{
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = $db->escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}
```

And the PHP code looks like that

```
$name=filter($_POST['name'], $db);
$title=filter($_POST['title'], $db);
$parent=filter($_POST['parent'],$db);
$switch=filter($_POST['switch'], $db);
    if($switch=''){
        echo "Return back and select an option";
        die();
    }
$parentcheck=filter($_POST['parentcheck'],$db);
    if($parentcheck=='0')
    {
        $parent=$parentcheck;
    }   
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$content = $db->real_escape_string( $purifier->purify( $_POST['content']) );

if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='Ok'){
    $result=$db->query("INSERT INTO menu (parent, name, showinmenu) VALUES ('$parent', '$name', '$switch'") or die($db->error);
    $result2=$db->query("INSERT INTO pages (id, title, content) VALUES ('<what?>', '$title', '$content'") or die($db->error);           
    }
```

And that's how my tables look like

Table named "pages"
[image]

And "menu"

[image]

**My questions are followings:**

---

1. I'm trying to get autoincremented `id` value from `menu` table after
   `('$parent', '$name', '$switch'")` insertion and set this `id` in `pages` table
   while inserting ($title, $content). How to do it? Is it possible with single
   query?
2. `$content`'s value is the text with HTML tags. I'm using html purifier.
   May I filter it's value too before inserting into db table? Any
   suggestion/advice?

Comment: Are you looking for mysql_insert_id()  function?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
$result2=$db->query("INSERT INTO pages (id, title, content) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$title', '$content'") or die($db->error);
```

Filtering using real_escape_string( ) should be safe. Is there something else that you want to filter?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using `mysqli` as the DB library, so you can use `$db->insert_id()` to retrieve the LAST id created by an insert operation by that particular DB handle. So your queries would become:

```
$result=$db->query("INSERT INTO menu (parent, name, showinmenu) VALUES ('$parent', '$name', '$switch'") or die($db->error);
$new_id = $db->insert_id();
$result2=$db->query("INSERT INTO pages (id, title, content) VALUES ($new_id, '$title', '$content'") or die($db->error);           
                                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

You can't really do it in a single query, as mysql does not make the ID value available for the insert_id function until AFTER the query completes. So you do have to do this in a 3 step process: insert, get id, insert again.

The rule for DB filtering (better known as escaping) is to escape ANYTHING that's user-provided. This even includes data you've retrieve in other db queries and are re-inserting. Escaping isn't really there as a security measure - it's there to make sure that whatever you're putting into the query string doesn't BREAK the query. Preventing SQL injection attacks is just a side effect of this.

Comment: Did you read the code of my `filter` function. $content's value is the text with HTML tags. I wanna filter `$content` too. Any advice about inserting html markup into db?

Comment: Purifier has nothing do with inserting html into a database. purifier just cleans up the html. How you want to store the data and what you're going to use it for afterwards is up to you. but purifier by itself is NOT enough to make some arbitrary html safe for database use. They're two completely different usage situations. Comparing apples and giraffes.

Comment: What you'd advice to do before inserting html into db table?

Comment: Try it like any other string data. Just because it's got some tags in it doesn't make it non-string. Though you'd want to rethink your filter function, since it destroys html/xml. Or have one specifically for html/xml.

Comment: can you help me to write one for html?

Comment: Like I said, just treat it as a string, but skip the purifier/strip_tags/etc... stuff.